# Material Text field label get cut when reload page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I'm using material ui in my react application and formik. All my textfields labels get cutted when the page is reloaded using f5, but when they are changed from another screen, this problem dont apeear.

```
<Grid className="input-grid-right" item xs={6}>
    <TextField
      error = {errors.email && touched.email && errors.email !== '' ? true : false}
      fullWidth
      label="E-mail"
      name="email"
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={values.email}
      variant="outlined"
    />
    <Typography variant="subtitle2">
      {errors.email && touched.email && errors.email}
    </Typography>
</Grid>
```

The full code of one page example is [here](https://pastebin.com/j0LULAPW):

```
 .input-grid-right{
      padding: 20px 15px 0px 0px;
      .error-message{
        color: #f44336;
      }
    }
```

[styles](https://pastebin.com/zA9Nuq4b):

Before reload page, the input stay like this
[okimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5boIE.jpg)
. When reload, text gets like this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiJ5k.jpg)

## Solution

In the footer of my page i had a library that was bugging all the screen.

[l18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) for internacionalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for some reason, when you refresh the page, the property width (of PrivateNotchedOutline) is set to 0. 
I would try overriding the width using MuiThemeProvider:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
   overrides: {
     PrivateNotchedOutline: {
       legend: {
         width: '265px !important',
       }
     }
   },
 });
```

And than wrap your component with ThemeProvider:

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <Grid>
      <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="Como gostaria de ser chamad  o ou chamada?"
          name="name"
          value={"hello"}
          variant="outlined"
      />
      <Typography variant="subtitle2">
         {errors.email && touched.email && errors.email}
      </Typography>

   </Grid>
  </ThemeProvider>
```

You can refer to this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cl261?fontsize=14

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: This approach is good, but the label gets wrong beacuse you are putting it manually. but i found the solution already, tanks for it!